# Get Date Object from Date in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Does the fullCalendar API have a way to get a date object from a date?
I need to get the cell for a specific date.  Is this possible?

IE, if I wanted to manually trigger a dayclick event, I would need the cell.

**EDIT**

I don't know if I was clear enough in my small blurb above.  Full Calendar can be thought of as a big table with cells, and each cell corresponds to a date for that month(in month view), when the month is changed, the same cells are recycled and given new data to display.  The problem is that the name or id of the cell has nothing to do with a date.  So lets say I wanted to change the background of a cell based on a date, `changeBackGround('01/01/2012','blue');`  As far as I can tell, this couldn't work because there is no way to grab a specific cell in the table just by using a date.  I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar has a callback [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) that fires when you click on any date, from there you could look to see if it matches your criteria.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var myDate = new Date();
        if(date.getTime() === myDate.getTime()){
            //it's that time!
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set some external access methods up, you could use the eventRender option to add an ID to an event, or data or other attributes. eventRender gives you access to the event data for that event and the event element, so you could make an ID with date string in it for example... hope this helps